# Aggregate Budgets by Customers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: **customers** and **budgets**.
I need to get all customers with the related budgets inside an array.
My problem is, I need to start the aggregate from the budgets collection.

Also, I need to return customers who don't have any budgets related.

I need a list with something like this:

```js
customer: {
  Id: Guid,
  Name: string,
  CpfCnpj: number,
  AccountantId: Guid
  Budgets: []
}
```

How can I do that?

Here the [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/reGKD731Qzk)

Comment: "I need to start the aggregate from the budgets collection." - why? It's trivial to do other way round

Comment: It has to do with the structure of the application. If I manage this way, that will change very little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to `"$project"`/etc. the results somewhat differently, but here's one way to output a document for each customer with an array of their budgets (or an empty array if there is no `budgets` document for them).

```js
db.budgets.aggregate([
  { // get customer docs with possible budgets
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "customers",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "budgets",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "CustomerId",
            "as": "budgets"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { // only keep budgets with a customer
    "$match": {
      "name": {"$exists": true}
    }
  },
  { // "budgets" set to empty array if missing
    "$set": {
      "budgets": {
        "$ifNull": ["$budgets", [] ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fz3arI8NPQT).

If `"$unionWith"` (introduced in MongoDB version 4.4) is unavailable, here's another way to do it by "transforming" (first four stages below) the original queried collection (here, `budgets`) into the desired collection (here, `customers`).  The remainder of the pipeline is a simple `"$lookup"` to get the desired info.

```js
db.budgets.aggregate([
  {"$limit": 1},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "customers",
      "pipeline": [],
      "as": "customers"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$customers"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$customers"},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "budgets",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "CustomerId",
      "as": "budgets"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-jHmIzCtsiG).

Comment: What if, the version of Mongo is 4.2.21 and does not have the $unionWith?

Comment: @DValdirMartins I added another option to the answer.